# Method for converting a Document from the index into a SolrDocument suitable for inclusion in a SolrQueryResponse

Tags: solr, upgrade, solrcloud, solr5

Struggling to find method for converting a Document from the index into a SolrDocument suitable for inclusion in a SolrQueryResponse for solr-core-5.5.2.jar

solr-core-5.2.1.jar had an **ResponseWriterUtil.toSolrDocument(Document doc, IndexSchema schema)** which is removed from solr-core-5.3.0 version

Thanks in advance

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ResponseWriterUtil class [has been replaced](https://gitlab.cecs.anu.edu.au/tsujamin/lucene-solr/commit/8ab21aa657c6c1d5ae05080a4500d527ad120b4f) with [DocsStreamer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/response/DocsStreamer.html) (`org.apache.solr.response.DocsStreamer`).

Depending on the API version, you either [give it it's parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_5_2/solr-core/org/apache/solr/response/DocsStreamer.html) from the ResultContext (for 5.5.2):

```
DocsStreamer(DocList docList, Query query, SolrQueryRequest req, ReturnFields returnFields)
static SolrDocument getDoc(Document doc, IndexSchema schema)
```

[or in newer versions](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/response/DocsStreamer.html), you give it the resultcontext directly:

```
DocsStreamer(ResultContext rctx) 
static SolrDocument getDoc(Document doc, IndexSchema schema)
```

If you use the constructor you get an iterator over the doclist from the result context, and you can use `.next()` to move to the next document as necessary.